# Force custom namespace with .Net client

Tags: c#, soap, namespaces, client

Our web service only accepts calls with namespace

```
<soapenv:Envelop>...
```

The .Net client automatically generates

```
<soap:Envelop> ...
```

How do you force the client to generate "soapenv" instead of "soap"?

Comment: What a broken web service is that? The **XML namespace prefix** should really not matter - as long as it refers to the correct XML namespace....

Comment: The web service is seriously messed up

Comment: So why aren't you fixing the **actual problem** (the totally messed up web service)?? You shouldn't waste your time trying to modify your code to cater to a broken web service....

Comment: You know I wouldn't be posting this if I could. This is what the client wants...